# What keyboard shortcut did I accidentally press at the login screen that killed the window manager?

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard-shortcuts, troubleshooting, plasma5

Mystery time! I'm using a Thinkpad T450s, running Kubuntu 20.04.3 and KDE Plasma 5.18.5. Today I decided to wipe off my keyboard. To do this I locked the screen, and gently wiped the keys from left to right, and back right to left with a lightly damp cloth. I've done this many times before, usually with no side effects, other than the username/password field being filled with random letters. This time was different, however.

My retelling of the story from this point on may not be 100% accurate, as it all happened quickly: The screen quickly flashed black and the lock screen returned. No big deal, I thought and tried logging in. First it seemed like the login would take a little longer, so I assumed I had somehow restarted X and would be greeted with a fresh login. But KDE's loading animation kept going.

At this point, I instinctively did what I usually do in a situation like that and pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to enter a text virtual terminal. A quick run of `ps aux` confirmed that my apps were still running. Going back to terminal 1 (the graphical one) I somehow managed to switch focus to my running apps, which were now displayed on top of the login screen. They were all missing the window bezel, the classic symptom of the window manager dying. I managed to close Chrome and Sublime gracefully, whereas Signal for some reason was showing a black window instead of its UI for some reason. (Pictured below.) I confirmed that this window really was Signal by killing its process from another VT. Finally, trying to login from the now visible login prompt seemed to just not work. After entering my password, the screen remained. After a manual reboot, the system now works fine.

[image: KDE login screen with a black window on top]

So, the question is, what keyboard shortcut did I manage to press by running a cloth over it, that put my OS in this weird state described above? Because of the wiping motion, the combinations are probably limited to combos of fairly adjacent keys. And another consideration is that the keyboard shortcut may not have been one that explicitly kills the window manager, but one that somehow triggered a bug that had this as a side effect.

Comment: this looks like a bug, nothing else.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sure. It's still useful to narrow down what caused it.

Comment: Long time ago the combination was Ctrl+Alt+Backspace